# Merge [html-encode], [htmlencode] and [html-encoding] and many similar

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Merge tags:

1. 1st group

   [html-encode](/questions/tagged/html-encode) x 132

   [htmlencode](/questions/tagged/htmlencode) x 62

   [html-encoding](/questions/tagged/html-encoding) x 16 (Target)
2. 2nd Group

   [html-entities](/questions/tagged/html-entities) x 307 (Target)

   [htmlentities](/questions/tagged/htmlentities) x 126
3. 3rd Group

   [htmleditor](/questions/tagged/htmleditor) x 115

   [html-editor](/questions/tagged/html-editor) x 20 (Target)

Out of these groups only one tag in group should be present. Merge each group into one tag  (Target) and give others as synonyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've merged:

- [html-entity](/questions/tagged/html-entity), [htmlentities](/questions/tagged/htmlentities) with [html-entities](/questions/tagged/html-entities)
- [htmleditor](/questions/tagged/htmleditor) with [html-editor](/questions/tagged/html-editor)

I didn't want to touch the [html-encode](/questions/tagged/html-encode) group because [html-encode](/questions/tagged/html-encode) could be referring to the [`HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode.aspx) and requires further review.

Comment: It may have been a minor mistake to merge `htmlentities` with the `-entity` and `-entities` tags; the hypehenless one matches a PHP function name, while the other two discuss the actual entities.  I don't think too many people are going to care, but some might.

Comment: @Charles FUUUUUUUU.  We need to look for [`html-entities` with `php`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+html-entities) - Any of these look wrong?

Comment: @casperOne: Then can we merge [tag:htmlencode] into [tag:html-encode]?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk No, that wouldn't make sense, because there are questions with `html-encode` that are on non ASP.NET questions.

Comment: @casperOne, none of them look *wrong* really, as questions about the `htmlentities` function are almost always going to be discussing HTML entities.  It's just that a function name was clobbered here.  That said, we don't really need a tag for every function in every language.

Comment: @Charles I'm generally of that disposition as well, as most function names can be *too* specific.